# Issues styling contact form (input and textarea)

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues styling the attached contact form.

Does anyone have any idea or suggestions on how I can accomplish this effect?

In the image, it looks like the "Labels" are incorporated into the input textbox.

Upon hover:

1) I want the Labels to stay in their fixed position, while the input text appears beside the each label.

2) The Label and input box border should also be highlighted a different colour from the input text.

```
I expect inputs like this
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIcbQ.png

```
from this fiddle
```

[jsfiddele](http://jsfiddle.net/mgmBE/3/)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: We don't see any attachments?

Comment: use `:focus` instead of `:hover`.

Comment: Hi all, updated the OG post with the image.

I tried using code similar to the one found here http://jsfiddle.net/mgmBE/3/ (with DIVs and input forms) but I wasn't able to adjust it so the text changes colour as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:focus` selector to change the color or any style when click on textbox.

try this one:

```
.input-container {
   position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.input-container input {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow:none;
}

.input-container .unit {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 3px;
    right: -3px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 45px;
}
.input-container input:focus{
  border-color:green;
  color:green;
}
.input-container input:focus + .unit{
  color:green
} 

<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" value="102.95" name="" />
    <span class="unit">Volts</span>
</div>
<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" value="30" name="" />
    <span class="unit">Kilos</span>
</div>
<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" value="64" name="" />
    <span class="unit">km/h</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mgmBE/110/)

as i suggest in comment to use `:focus`, i hope it will help

```
.input-container input {
    width: 100%; 
    border-color: grey;
    border-bottem:1px;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-top:0px;
}

.input-container .unit {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    color: grey;
  padding-left: 5px;
    width: 45px;

}
input{color:grey; text-align:right;}
input:focus {
    color: green;
    border-color: green;
    outline:none;

}
.input-container input:focus + .unit{
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way I can align the input text to the left of the labels?

Comment: yeah! i will fix this for you @amuese